# Sort a linked list based on the parameter field

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

The following is a code of sorting a singly linked list. Where each node has the pointer to the next node. and a data field. Here I can't pass parameter to my sortList() function.

```java
public class LL {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size;

    public LL() {
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public void sortList() {  
        //Node current will point to head  
        Node current = head, index = null;  
        int temp;  
          
        if(head == null) {  
            return;  
        }  
        else {  
            while(current != null) {  
                //Node index will point to node next to current  
                index = current.next;  
                  
                while(index != null) {  
                    //If current node's data is greater than index's node data, swap the data between them  
                    if(current.data > index.data) {  
                        temp = current.data;  
                        current.data = index.data;  
                        index.data = temp;  
                    }  
                    index = index.next;  
                }  
                current = current.next;  
            }      
        }
```

But what I want to do is pass a parameter to the list. Here my nodes have unique_id, hours, price, teacher_id.
I want to sort my list based on what I pass to the sortfunction.
Like if I pass int price to the method, I want my list to be sorted based on the price. If I pass hours, I want the list to be sorted on the basis of hours.
So that it sorts based on that specific field something like the following code:

```java
public class LL {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size;

    public LL() {
        this.size = 0;
    }

    private class Node {
        private String unique_id;
        private int hours = -1;
        private String teacher_id;
        private String topic_name;
        private int price = -1;
        private LL ll_of_ll;
        private Node next;
    

    public void sortList(int price) {  
        //Node current will point to head  
        Node current = head, index = null;  
        int temp;  
          
        if(head == null) {  
            return;  
        }  
        else {  
            while(current != null) {  
                //Node index will point to node next to current  
                index = current.next;  
                  
                while(index != null) {  
                    //If current node's data is greater than index's node data, swap the data between them  
                    if(current.price > index.price) {  
                        temp = current.price;  
                        current.price = index.price;  
                        index.price = temp;  
                    }  
                    index = index.next;  
                }  
                current = current.next;  
            }      
        }
```

Comment: What language? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Java Language, Edited

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a `Comparator` as a parameter to your sort function.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.

```
    public void sortList(Comparator<Node> comparator) {
```

Then

```
                    if(comparator.compare(current, price) > 0) { 
                        temp = current.price;  
                        current.price = index.price;  
                        index.price = temp;  
                    }
```

Now you can choose what to sort by with:

```
ll.sort(Comparator.comparing(node -> node.getPrice()));
```

or:

```
ll.sort(Comparator.comparing(node -> node.getTeacher_id()))
```

Comment: I can't use any generics as per the constraints mentioned in the problem.

Comment: Ah right. I missed that one. (where can I find that constraint?) Can you be confident that the properties in your Node are Comparable? If you, you could implement a subclass of Comparator. That would move the generic outside the problem space. Otherwise, if generics aren't allowed entirely in your project, you could implement your own.
I'll adjust my answer later.

Comment: Can you tell me why Generics can't be used? That might give us some information of what answers are and aren't acceptable. My instinct would be to move the type parameter somewhere else, but if it's a Java version constraint, then that won't work. And then, lambda functions won't work either.